# is there a way to rename the range name in y-axis in chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
rank <- as.numeric(rank)
rank[is.na(rank)] <- 0
```

scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:28)

[image]

that's now the result i have but i want it to become 'new' 0 1 2 3 ... as shown:

[image]

it has a few 'new' to the rank. therefore I changed it to be numeric format and then the 'new' become NA. however I want to show it then I make it NA to be 0. but now I want the 0 in the plot to become a 'new' word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `labels` argument to `replace()` the first value:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  aes(y = 0:10) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:10, labels = ~ replace(.x, 1, "New"))
```

[image]